# How to add new cluster in ArgoCD (use config file of Rancher)? - the server has asked for the client to provide credentials

Tags: kubernetes, devops, rancher, argocd

I want to add a new cluster in addition to the default cluster on ArgoCD but when I add it, I get an error:
FATA[0001] rpc error: code = Unknown desc = REST config invalid: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
I use the command `argocd cluster add cluster-name`
I download config file k8s of Rancher.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved my problem but welcome other solutions from everyone :D
First, create a secret with the following content:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  namespace: argocd # same namespace of argocd-app
  name: mycluster-secret
  labels:
    argocd.argoproj.io/secret-type: cluster
type: Opaque
stringData:
  name: cluster-name # Get from clusters - name field in config k8s file.
  server: https://mycluster.com # Get from clusters - name - cluster - server field in config k8s file.
  config: |
    {
      "bearerToken": "<authentication token>",
      "tlsClientConfig": {
        "insecure": false,
        "caData": "<base64 encoded certificate>" 
      }
    }
```

`bearerToken` - Get from users - user - token field in config k8s file.
`caData` -  Get from clusters - name - cluster - certificate-authority-data field in config k8s file.
Then, apply this yaml file and the new cluster will be automatically added to ArgoCD.
I found the solution on github:
https://gist.github.com/janeczku/b16154194f7f03f772645303af8e9f80